A kind of Converse for "Annihilator as the intersection of $n-d$ linear functionals' kernels"
Suppose $W \subset V$ is a $d$-dimensional subspace of $V$ which is $n$ dimensional. Let $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \cdots \alpha_d \}$ be a basis for $W$, and $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \cdots \alpha_d, \alpha_{d+1} \cdots \alpha_n \}$ be the basis for $V$. Let $f_1,f_2 \cdots f_n$ be the dual bases (of the dual space $V^*$) dual to $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\cdots \alpha_n$ in such a way that $$f_i(\alpha_j)=\delta_{ij} $$
Then we can conclude the following: (See Hoffman & Kunze 2nd Ed. page-102, corollary-1)

$f_{d+1},f_{d+2} \cdots f_{n}$ are $n$ functionals in the dual space that form a basis for $W^0$ (the annihilator space, defined as $W^0:=\{f \in V^*: f(x)=0, \ \forall x \in W\}$).

$\cap_{i=d+1}^n\operatorname{ker}(f_{i})=W$


Now I ask the following question, taking motivation from the above basis:
Suppose $\{\gamma_1,\gamma_2 \cdots \gamma_{n-d}\}$ are $n-d$ functionals in $W^0$ that form a basis for $W^0$. Can I prove (or disprove/ provide counterexample) that $\cap_{i=1}^{n-d}\operatorname{ker}(\gamma_i)=W$?
They say don't lie to doctors, lawers and stackexchange users, so I'll come clean: I don't really have any approach here, but it would be nice if this were true for another result that I need.

Here's one approach using symmetry of duality: extend $\{\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_{n-d}\}$ to a basis $\{\gamma_1,\ldots,\gamma_{n-d},\gamma_{n-d+1},\ldots,\gamma_n\}$ of $V^*$, and let $\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ be its dual basis in $V^{**}=V$. Then by (1), we know $\{\alpha_{n-d+1},\ldots,\alpha_n\}$ form a basis of $W^{00}=W$, so by (2) we know $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-d}\ker\gamma_i=W$.
Here's another approach: define $\Gamma:V\to\mathbb{F}^{n-d}$ by $\Gamma(x)=(\gamma_1(x),\ldots,\gamma_{n-d}(x))$. Then $\ker\Gamma=\bigcap_{i=1}^{n-d}\ker\gamma_i$. Clearly $W\subseteq\ker\Gamma$, and $\Gamma$ has nullity $d$ since it has rank $n-d$ (why?), so $W=\ker\Gamma$.

Really nice answer!! I havent formally learnt $V^{**}$, but I guess this is how Hoffman does it. The 2nd approach is really slick! (My argument for (why?) is that: $\gamma_1, \cdots \gamma_{n-d}$, being a Lin independent set, is part of a basis of $V^*$ and we can extend it. Hence, there exists $e_1,e_2 \cdots e_n$ in $V$, linearly independent, so that $\gamma_i(e_j)=\delta_{ij}$. This allows us surjectivity since we can exploit the relation $\gamma_i(\alpha \in V)= x_i$ the $i-$th coordinate of $\alpha$ relative to $e_1,e_2 \cdots$). Is this fine? do u have a slicker argument ? :P

@nickbros123 Right.

Apart from the really nice methods given by @blargoner, there is another perhaps hack way of getting to this result:
Let $W$ be a $d-$ dimensioned subspace of $n-$ dimensioned $V$. We know that, if we assume a basis $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \cdots \alpha_k$ for $W$ (and extend it to $\mathbb{A}=\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \cdots \alpha_n$ basis of $V$), the corresponding dual bais, dual to this $\mathbb{A}$, i.e, $f_{d+1},f_{d+2} \cdots f_{n}$, gotten from the relation $f_{i}(\alpha_j)=\delta_{ij}$ forms a basis for $W^0$. Moreover, we can also show that $\cap_{i=1}^{n-d}\operatorname{ker}(f_{d+i})=W$ (see above mentioned corollary from Hoffman).  Now consider $\gamma_1, \cdots \gamma_{n-d}$ a basis for $W^0$. We know that $\gamma_1, \cdots \gamma_{n-d}$ are each a linear combination of $f_d,f_{d+1}\cdots f_{n}$. $$\gamma_j=\sum_{k=1}^{n-d}c_{kj}f_{d+k} $$ for each $k=1$ to $k=n-d$. Hence, if say $x$ is a vector that is in $W=\cap_{i=1}^{n-d}\operatorname{ker}(f_{d+i})$, then by virtue of the above linear combination, it is also in $\cap_{i=1}^{n-d}\operatorname{ker}(\gamma_i) \implies \cap_{i=1}^{n-d}\operatorname{ker}(\gamma_i) \subseteq \cap_{i=1}^{n-d}\operatorname{ker}(f_{d+i})$.
But the reverse argument can also be applied (by considering $f_{d+i}$ to be the linear combination of $\{\gamma_i\}$) to show that $\cap_{i=1}^{n-d}\operatorname{ker}(f_{i+d}) \subseteq \cap_{i=1}^{n-d}\operatorname{ker}(\gamma_i)$ which finally gives us the desired result:
$$\cap_{i=1}^{n-d}\operatorname{ker}(f_{i+d}) = \cap_{i=1}^{n-d}\operatorname{ker}(\gamma_i)=W$$
